# Puppet Unable to run Services in chroot environment

Tags: mysql, service, puppet, openstack

Im building a Ubuntu Live ISO with all Openstack services installed and configured for a single node setup(all services installed on same node).
To build this ISO I'm creating a chroot env. by unwrapping Live Ubuntu ISO.
While doing Openstack installation with puppet, puppet is unable to start services in the chroot env.

```
Eg:
/etc/init.d/mysql status #gives this O/P
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql status

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the status(8) utility, e.g. status mysql

service mysql status
shows no output.
```

Any pointers will be appreciated :)

Comment: Puppet output? Return codes?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that puppet is indeed awkward in `chroot` jails because the gathering of `facter` facts does not work appropriately (or something in that vein).

To the problem at hand, though - you way want to make your `service` resources use an appropriate `provider` is Puppet doesn't select the right one, e.g.

```
service { "mysql": provider => upstart }
```

or even

```
Service { provider => upstart } # resource default at global scope
```

See the [list of service providers](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#service-providers). Note how Puppet is supposed to select the appropriate one on its own, so this may indeed be a problem with the `chroot` and how it skews `facter`'s deliberations.